# Confidence interval without standard deviation

Tags: probability, statistics

> From a list of stock mutual funds, 52 funds were selected at
>   random.
>        Of the funds chosen, it was found that 19 required a minimum 
>       initial investment under \$1,000.
>
> (a) Construct a 90 percent confidence interval for the true proportion
>   requiring an initial investment under \$1,000.
>
> (b) May normality be assumed? Explain.

I am not sure how to go about solving this. I am used to answering these kinds of questions when I know the mean and standard deviation.

How do I determine these?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Say the true proportion of funds that require an initial investment of less than 
\$1000 is $p$. If we select $n$ funds at random with replacement, then the probability that of the $n$ funds we sampled, $k$ require an initial investment of less than \$1000 follows a binomial distribution with probability parameter $p$. Under certain conditions, you can use a normal approximation to this binomial distribution to calculate a confidence interval. You do not know $p$, but you can estimate it with $\hat{p}$, the sample proportion. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) for more information. The method I've outlined is not the best way to solve this problem, but I believe it to be the simplest. Better methods are detailed in the article I linked to.